# How to call ArrayList from Controller to view in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, arraylist

i want to call Arraylist in view. I will explain my issue clearly.

**My Controller Code**

```
   public ActionResult customerid()
    {
       List<Customer> n = (from c in db.Customers where c.IsDeleted == false  select c).ToList();
        var customertype = string.Empty;

     for (var i = 0; i < n.Count; i++)
        {
            var objCustomerName = n[i].DisplayName;
            var objCustomerID = n[i].CustomerID;
            var objCusCreatedDate=n[i].CreatedDate;
    var objNextDate = objCusCreatedDate.GetValueOrDefault().AddDays(120);
    var salescount = (from sc in db.SalesOrders where sc.CustomerID==objCustomerID && sc.CreatedDate >= objCusCreatedDate && sc.CreatedDate<= objNextDate select sc.SalesOrderID).Count();

            if (salescount <= 3&& salescount> 0)
            {
                customertype = "Exisiting  Customer";
            }
            else if (salescount >= 3)
            {
                customertype = "Potential Customer";
            }
            else
            {
                customertype = "New Customer";
            }

            ArrayList obj = new ArrayList();
            {
                obj.Add(new string[] { objCustomerName, customertype, salescount.ToString()});

            }

             var details = obj;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**My View Model**

```
 public class CustomerTypeViewModel
{

    public System.Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string SalesCount { get; set; }
    public string CustomerType { get; set; }

}
```

I want to call this array list in view. How I do that? That is i am generating one view based on controller code I need output same as like which is mentioned in the below image .

**Wanted Output**

[Wanted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BEXs.jpg)

So i put all the fields (which i going to give as a column in View) in Array list. Now i want to call that Arraylist

```
     obj.Add(new string[] { objCustomerName, customertype, salescount.ToString()});
```

in view . How I do that? I tried to explain my issue as per my level best. please understand my problem and tell me one solution. I am new to MVC so please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Create a view model with the properties you want to display in the view (`CustomerName` and `customertype`) and return a collection of that model to the view

Comment: ya i created one view model also public class CustomerTypeViewModel
    {

        public System.Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string SalesCount { get; set; }
        public string CustomerType { get; set; }

    }

Comment: How to return a collection of the model to view Stephen?? please explain me in detail ?? And sorry to disturb you gain..

Comment: Initialize a new `List<CustomerTypeViewModel>`. Inside the loop, add a new instance of a `CustomerTypeViewModel` to you list, then return that list to the view - `return View(yourList);` and use a loop in the view to display them.

Comment: ok stephen lets i have a try and if i got issue means i will tell that problem again as a reply

Comment: Stephen 
[Return Error][2]
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3xj3w.jpg  i getting this error ..

Comment: You need to declare `List<CustomerTypeViewModel> obj = new List<CustomerTypeViewModel>();` **before** the loop

Comment: ok lets i have a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
List<CustomerTypeViewModel> obj = new List<CustomerTypeViewModel>();
obj.Add(new CustomerTypeViewModel(){
  CustomerName = objCustomerName,
  CustomerType = customertype,
  SalesCount = salescount.ToString()
});

return View(obj);
```

In your view

```
@model IEnumerable<CustomerTypeViewModel>

and display values like this

@if (Model.Any()) {
  foreach (var m in Model) {
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => m.CustomerName)
     @Html.DisplayFor(x => m.CustomerType)
  }
}
```

Comment: Dont forget return View(obj); in you controller

Comment: mhmm ok eminem . i will return

Comment: Eminem i am getting one error     [Return Error][2]
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/3xj3w.jpg                                                                 because i cant write the return function inside of for loop so it showing obj is soes not exist in the current content..

Comment: declare List<CustomerTypeViewModel> obj = new List<CustomerTypeViewModel>(); OUTSIDE of your for loop. Please select as answer if correct

Comment: if i declare outside of the for loop means it will show error near to  CustomerName = objCustomerName, because it is in inside of for loop..